# What's wrong with static utility classes, versus beans?

Tags: java, object-oriented, static

My inclination is to make these methods static:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.persistence.*;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Article;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Newsgroup;

class DatabaseUtils {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseUtils.class.getName());
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("USENETPU");
    private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public int getMax(Folder folder) {
        int max = 0;
        String ng = folder.getFullName();
        String queryString = "select max(article.messageNumber) from Article article left join article.newsgroup newsgroup where newsgroup.newsgroup = '" + ng + "'";
        try {
            max = (Integer) em.createQuery(queryString).getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.info("setting max to zero");
        }
        LOG.severe(folder.getFullName() + "\t" + max);
        return max;
    }

    public void persistArticle(Message message, Folder folder) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String fullNewsgroupName = folder.getFullName();
        Newsgroup newsgroup = null;
        int max = getMax(folder);
        TypedQuery<Newsgroup> query = em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Newsgroup n WHERE n.newsgroup = :newsGroupParam", Newsgroup.class);
        query.setParameter("newsGroupParam", fullNewsgroupName);
        try {
            newsgroup = query.getSingleResult();
            LOG.fine("found " + query.getSingleResult());
        } catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException e) {
            LOG.fine(e + "\ncould not find " + fullNewsgroupName);
            newsgroup = new Newsgroup(folder);
            em.persist(newsgroup);
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
            LOG.warning("\nshould never happen\t" + fullNewsgroupName);
        }
        Article article = new Article(message, newsgroup);
        em.persist(article);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void close() {
        em.close();
        emf.close();//necessary?
    }
}
```

However, I'm quite sure that I'm in the minority!  Why?

A quick look at [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) shows that this isn't a strange or odd approach.  The object itself keeps no state, really, so why would a bean or POJO be **preferred** to static methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the object contains an entity manager which has state. In a simple application having only one shared entity manager might work but if you made this into an EJB in a Java-EE application you would definitely want each request to use it's own entity manager.

Comment: Ok, I grudgingly take your point vis a vis the entity manager, but I was more asking in the general.

Comment: @Thufir: Sometimes you just can't answer the OP's specific question but you have some useful comment on another part of the code (like Eelke's comment here, I guess). It's fine, ontopic and encouraged on this site (according to the FAQ).

Answer (score 5):

Static helper classes makes testing harder. Nick Malik has a good article on this topic: [Killing the Helper class, part two](http://vanguardea.com/killing-the-helper-class-part-two/).

Mocking non-static methods is closer to OOP and easier than static ones. Another gain is that you'll have simple tests: simple tests for the utility/helper class and simple tests for the clients of the utility class; the tests of the client classes don't have to know the internals of the utility class, and you don't need a DatabaseUtilsTestHelper class to keep in one place the mocking logic for the helper class. The linked article is worth the reading.

Some other notes:

- Try not using short variable names like `ng`. They are hard to read.
- `persistArticle` does not close the transaction in every path. You should rollback it in the `finally` block if it's still active:

  ```
   final EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
   transaction.begin();
   try {
       ...    
       transaction.commit();
   } finally {
       if (transaction.isActive()) {
           transaction.rollback();
       }
   }
  ```
- `persistArticle` does not use the value of `max`, therefore the `getMax` call seems unnecessary.

Comment: Please expand on "Mocking non-static methods is closer to OOP and easier than static ones. " --**why**?

Comment: @Thufir: Because you don't need any trick (such as proxies, byte-code manipulation) to change the behavior of a static method for only a testcase. You can do it with pure polymorphism (which is a core OOP feature).