# Closing a ResultSet and rethrowing an Exception

Tags: java, exception

Is this an acceptable way to make sure a java.sql.ResultSet is always closed, and also make sure that an Exception caught is propagated to the caller?

Please don't hesitate to review other aspects of this sample as well.

```
public void updateReplicationStatus(BeanReplicationTask taskBean, String strStatus) throws Exception {
    String strSelect = this.createReplicationSelectStatement(taskBean);
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        resultSet = DerbyDog.getResultSet(strSelect);
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            resultSet.updateString(COLUMN_STATUS, strStatus);
            resultSet.updateRow();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer the questions: 2 times yes.

Answer (score 7):

## Close a ResultSet/Resource

If you are using java 7 then I would recommend to use [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

it will take care of closing ResultSet for you and make your code a little cleaner.

```
public void updateReplicationStatus(BeanReplicationTask taskBean, String strStatus) throws Exception {
    String strSelect = this.createReplicationSelectStatement(taskBean);       
    try (ResultSet resultSet = DerbyDog.getResultSet(strSelect) {            
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            resultSet.updateString(COLUMN_STATUS, strStatus);
            resultSet.updateRow();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } 
}
```

## Exception Handling

personal I prefer to wrap my own exceptions around generic exceptions.

That way I can throw a more precise exception with a comment to help myself when debugging

```
public void updateReplicationStatus(BeanReplicationTask taskBean, String strStatus)   throws ReplicationStatusException {
    String strSelect = this.createReplicationSelectStatement(taskBean);       
    try (ResultSet resultSet = DerbyDog.getResultSet(strSelect) {            
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            resultSet.updateString(COLUMN_STATUS, strStatus);
            resultSet.updateRow();
        }
    } catch (SqlException e) {
        throw new ReplicationStatusException("update ReplicationStatus failed because of a SQLException", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ReplicationStatusException("update ReplicationStatus failed because of an unexpected exception", e)
    }   
}
```

that's about my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

1. +1 to Alex and an improvement for Java 6: you could eliminate the `null` check in the `finally` block if you move the `DerbyDog.getResultSet` call before the `try` block. If it's inside the `try` block and it throws an exception you won't be able to `close` the `ResultSet` because the reference will remain `null`. *Guideline 1-2: Release resources in all cases* in the [Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language, Version 4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html) documentation could be helpful.
2. The `catch` block is unnecessary here. Exceptions will be propagated without it.
3. Be aware of static helper classes. `DerbyDog` seems one of them. You might find [my former answer about it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/14361/7076) useful.

```
ResultSet resultSet = DerbyDog.getResultSet(strSelect);
try {
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        resultSet.updateString(COLUMN_STATUS, strStatus);
        resultSet.updateRow();
    }
} finally {
        resultSet.close();
}
```