# Custom Script Editor

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, strings

I'm making my own *script editor* (in this case for `Arma: Cold War Assault`) because I want to learn and this is challenging enough.

Let me just get this out of the way: ***please don't tell me that I should do easier things. I want to do this anyway***.

So, basically I have the simple GUI for now with a working new/open/save file menu.

I've managed to highlight certain words with different colors (because I want to tackle the hardest part first) but it's **not efficient**.

I've come up with several ideas for the algorithm (didn't implement them all), but I want to know what you'do, if there's a certain way and what I am doing wrong.

This all happens inside a `JTextPane` class.

---

The arrays containing the reserved words:

```
Collections.addAll(keywords, "private", "public", "if", "not", "then", "else", "else if");          
Collections.addAll(operators, "+", "-", "=", "==", "?", "!","(", ")","{", "}", "_", "-", "^", "<", ">");            

ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> operators = new ArrayList<String>();
```

---

Everytime the user makes an update to the document, it get's updated:

```
@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    update();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    update();
}
```

---

When the user stops typing, it waits 500 ms to update the screen:

```
Timer t;

/**
 * Updates the text when user stops typing
 */
public void update(){

    if (t != null) {
        if (t.isRunning())
            t.stop();
    }

    t = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            String text = getText();                

            SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.BLACK);
            StyledDocument doc = getStyledDocument();
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, text.length(), attrs, true);

            int index = 0, carriage = 0;

            while ((index < text.length())) {

                if (text.codePointAt(index) == 10) {
                    carriage += 1;
                }

                for (String s : Keywords.listKeywords()) {                      
                    if (text.startsWith(s, index)){
                        changeColor(doc, reserved.get(s), index, carriage, s.length(), false);
                        index += s.length();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                for (String s : Keywords.listOperators()) {
                    if (text.startsWith(s, index)){
                        changeColor(doc, reserved.get(s), index, carriage, s.length(), false);
                        index += s.length();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                index++;
            }
            wordCount.setText("word count: " + index);
            System.out.println("Iterations took: "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

            t.stop();
        }
    });
    t.start();
}

private void changeColor(StyledDocument doc, Color color, int index, int carriage, int length, boolean replace) {
    SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, color);
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(index - carriage, length, attrs, replace);
}
```

How would I go about doing this more efficiently?

As of right now, with almost 145.000 words i have a delay of about 400 ms with 12 keywords and other words.

Comment: scanner.match().start() returns 0 whenever it starts a new line, so it doesn't know it is in a new line...

Comment: The code in revision 4 does not work so I've rollbacked it since it's off-topic here. I think it should be on Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 1):

As a general direction for improvement, your technique for finding those keywords uses `startsWith`, which will effectively compare any given character once per potential keyword or operator. If you switch to *regular expressions*, by compiling a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that matches *any keyword* or *any operator*, you build (what amounts to) a lookup table that typically allows one comparison per character, reducing the total number of comparisons significantly.

You can even use `Pattern.quote` to make building the String easier.

```
public Pattern fromList(List<String> strings) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  boolean isFirst = true;
  for (String string : strings) {
    if (!isFirst) {
      builder.append('|');
    }
    builder.append(Pattern.quote(string));
    isFirst = false;
  }
  return Pattern.compile(builder.toString());
}
```

After that, search for every occurrence of the String using either `Pattern.matcher()` (or `Scanner.next()`), which will save you those repeated comparisons. At that point you can use the `start` and `end` methods on `Matcher` (or the same on `Scanner.match()`).

I do notice that your algorithm will tend to highlight the first half of terms like `publicValue` even if the compiler does not detect it as a keyword. For this, you may want to customize the patterns you generate to match [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Thanks. Patterns are complicated for first use! I understand how it works, but: how would I make a pattern to match a set of fixed words, like "public, private, int, boolean". I managed to understand how to use to search for a pattern, but not for individual words.

Comment: Im using right now: Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(public+?)\\b").matcher(this.getText()); but surelly there are better ways i imagine.

Comment: The pipe symbol (`|`) means "or". Try "\\b(public|private|function)\\b" and so forth. Because you're in parens, the word would technically be "group 1" for the methods on Matcher, but since word boundaries are zero-length it'd work the same. Don't be afraid to generate the regex from your existing List. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the it's `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the text inside the `JTextPane`.
You could reduce it if you process only the modified regions of the document in the event listener.
I think [`DocumentEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html)'s `getLength()` and `getOffset()` method could help here.

Another notes:

1. ```
   int index = 0, carriage = 0;
   ```

   I'd put the variable declarations to separate lines. From Code Complete, 2nd Edition, p759:

   > With statements on their own lines, the code reads from top to bottom, instead
   >   of top to bottom and left to right. When you’re looking for a specific line of code,
   >   your eye should be able to follow the left margin of the code. It shouldn’t have to
   >   dip into each and every line just because a single line might contain two statements.
2. Be aware of static helper classes, like `Keywords`. You might find [my former answer about it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/14361/7076) useful.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't search through all the DocumentEvent's methods. getOffset() is perfect.